# Validating Form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm working on some JavaScript and have a few remaining issues with my validation that I need to have fixed, but haven't quite figured them out. This has to remain in JavaScript and unfortunately can't be done through JQuery. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have the following three problems:

The email has to be set with 64 character max length for the name and 252 character for the domain. It also needs to include standard validation practices.
       I have this set, but it ruins part of the function I have set already.

The contact checkboxes need to require at least two be selected out of the four.

The Submit button needs to display errors and then, return back with errors.

```js
//Javascript


function onFocus(el) {
  if (el.value == el.defaultValue){
    el.value = '';
  }
}
function isNumber(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
function isAlpha(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if ((charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122))
    return false;

  return true;
}
function isAlphanum(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode > 32))
    return false;

  return true;
}
function validate_form() {

  valid = true;

  if (document.myForm.firstname.value == "" || document.myForm.firstname.value == "abcd") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'First Name' box.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (document.myForm.lastname.value == "" || document.myForm.lastname.value == "abcdf") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'Last Name' box.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (document.myForm.address.value == "") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'Address' box.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (document.myForm.city.value == "") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'City' box.");
    valid = false;
  } 
  if (document.myForm.state.selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert ("Please select your State.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (document.myForm.zipcode.value == "") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'Zip Code' box.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (document.myForm.phone.value == "") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'Area Code' box.");
    valid = false;
  } 
  if (document.myForm.phone1.value == "") {
    alert ("Please fill in the 'Phone Number' box.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w{ ,64})*@\w+([\.-]?\w{ ,252})*(\.\w+)+$/.test(myForm.email.value)){
    return (true)
  } else {
    alert("Please Enter a Valid Email Address!")
    return false
  } 
  if (document.myForm.conemail.value != document.myForm.email.value){
    alert ("Please Confirm E-mail.");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (( document.myForm.preference[0].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.preference[1].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.preference[2].checked == false )){
    alert ( "Please choose your Meal Preference" );
    valid = false;
  }
  if (( document.myForm.contact[0].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.contact[1].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.contact[2].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.contact[3].checked == false ) && (document.myForm.contact.checked > 2)){
    alert ( "Please choose your Contact Method" );
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
}

/*function valThis() {
      var min = 1;
      var checkCont = document.getElementsByClassName('contact');
      for (var i = 0; i > checkCont.length; i++) {
        checkCont[i].onclick = function() {
          var checkCount = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < checkCont.length; i++) {
            checkCount += (checkCont[i].checked) ?  1 : 0;
          }
         if (checkCount < min) {
          alert("Please Select Two or more Contact Methods");

          this.checked = flase;
          }
        }
      }
    }*/
/*function valEmail() {

      if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w{ ,64})*@\w+([\.-]?\w{ ,252})*(\.\w+)+$/.test(myForm.email.value)){
        return (true)
      } else {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Email Address!")
        return false
      } 
    }*/

function mySubmit() {
  document.myForm.addEventListener( "submit", validate_form);
  document.myForm.addEventListener( "submit", valThis);
  document.myForm.addEventListener("submit", valEmail);
}
function myReset() {
  document.myForm.reset();
}
```

```css
form {
 font-family: sans-serif, serif;
 border: 3px solid black;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 max-height: 800px;
 width: 450px;
}
form input, form select{
 margin: 5px auto;
 padding: 2px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 
}
.pho {
 width: 25px;
}
.pho1 {
 width: 70px;
}
.pre1 {
 margin-left: 142px;
}
.con1 {
 margin-left: 32px;
}
#com{
 margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form Validation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/project-2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="myForm" onSubmit = "return mySubmit()" method="post">
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    First Name: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="abcd" onfocus="onFocus(this)" onkeypress="return isAlpha(event)"><br>
    Last Name: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="abcdf"onfocus="onFocus(this)"  onkeypress="return isAlpha(event)"><br>
    Address: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="address" onkeypress="return isAlphanum(event)" ><br>
    City: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="city" onkeypress="return isAlpha(event)" ><br>
    State: &ast;
    <select name="state">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="AL">AL</option>
      <option value="AK">AK</option>
      <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
      <option value="AR">AR</option>
      <option value="CA">CA</option>
      <option value="CO">CO</option>
      <option value="CT">CT</option>
      <option value="DE">DE</option>
      <option value="FL">FL</option>
      <option value="GA">GA</option>
      <option value="HI">HI</option>
      <option value="ID">ID</option>
      <option value="IL">IL</option>
      <option value="IN">IN</option>
      <option value="IA">IA</option>
      <option value="KS">KS</option>
      <option value="KY">KY</option>
      <option value="LA">LA</option>
      <option value="ME">ME</option>
      <option value="MD">MD</option>
      <option value="MA">MA</option>
      <option value="MI">MI</option>
      <option value="MN">MN</option>
      <option value="MS">MS</option>
      <option value="MO">MO</option>
      <option value="MT">MT</option>
      <option value="NE">NE</option>
      <option value="NV">NV</option>
      <option value="NH">NH</option>
      <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
      <option value="NM">NM</option>
      <option value="NY">NY</option>
      <option value="NC">NC</option>
      <option value="ND">ND</option>
      <option value="OH">OH</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="OR">OR</option>
      <option value="PA">PA</option>
      <option value="RI">RI</option>
      <option value="SC">SC</option>
      <option value="SD">SD</option>
      <option value="TN">TN</option>
      <option value="TX">TX</option>
      <option value="UT">UT</option>
      <option value="VT">VT</option>
      <option value="VA">VA</option>
      <option value="WA">WA</option>
      <option value="WV">WV</option>
      <option value="WI">WI</option>
      <option value="WY">WY</option>
    </select><br>
    Zip Code: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="5"><br>
    Phone: &ast;
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="pho" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="3">
    <input type="text" name="phone1" class="pho1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="7"><br>
    <label>E-mail: &ast; </label>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    Confirm E-mail: &ast;
    <input type="email" name="conemail"><br>
    <div id="pre">Meal Preference: &ast;
      <input type="radio" name="preference" class="pre" value="vegan">Vegan<br>
      <input type="radio" name="preference" class="pre1" value="vegetarian">Vegetarian<br>
      <input type="radio" name="preference" class="pre1" value="nonvegetarian">Non-Vegetarian<br></div>
    Contact Method: &ast; 
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" class="con1" class="contact" value="phone">Phone
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" class="contact" value="email">E-mail<br>
    (select more than one)
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" class="contact" value="mail">Mail
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" class="contact" value="linkedIn">LinkedIn<br>
    Comments:
    <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40" maxlength="250"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="mySubmit()" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" onclick="myReset()" value="Reset">Reset</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a pattern for the input fields and check the validity on submit.

Comment: Most of it validates, but the three problems I'm having are limited my ability to finish this code.

Answer (score 0):

When Html form is submitted, the function declared in the onSubmit attributte runs for validating the fields.

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit = "return mySubmit()" method="post">
```

If `mySubmit()` returns false, the data is not submitted because there was an error. So you need to return proper boolean from this function. For example:

```
function mySubmit() {
    return valEmail() && validate_form() && valThis() && validateThat();
}
```

Can't test your code now, but this is what I can see. There could be other issues.